# Get FileName in SSIS

Tags: ssis-2012

I'm new to SSIS, how can I get the Excel FileName that I'm trying to upload and assign it to a variable for later usage?
I've tried to do some research but I didn't get anything helpful.

Comment: try a Foreach Loop container and let us know if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Foreach Loop container:

1. Set the enumerator to Foreach File enumerator
2. Point it towards the folder where your excel file is located
3. tell it to look for `.xls` or `.xlsx` files
4. On Variable Mappings, create a variable called `FileName`

Obviously if you have more than one file in there, it will only give you the last file name.